# How to find and fix duplicate project entries in dotnet solution file?

Tags: c#, msbuild, neovim, omnisharp

I use Neovim with OmniSharp and it doesn't load any of 34 projects that are showing in VisualStudio 2022

OmniSharp logs showing this error

```
[fail]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        The project system 'OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem' threw exception during initialization.
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem.GetProjectPathsAndIdsFromSolutionOrFilter(String solutionOrFilterFilePath) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectSystem.cs:line 197
   at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem.Initalize(IConfiguration configuration) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectSystem.cs:line 117
   at OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer.Initialize(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, CompositionHost compositionHost) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.Host\WorkspaceInitializer.cs:line 54
```

So I assume there should be duplicates in the sln file. I sorted file with :%sort u and found a couple of duplicates, deleted them, but it didn't work. What else can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the OP has resolved their issue, I will provide some general guidelines regarding the .sln file.

When creating a new project, it will be referenced twice in the .sln file. The first reference appears as follows:

```
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "UnitTests", "UnitTest\UnitTests.csproj", "{A1EEBF59-8295-4354-927F-CE696137BF5C}"
EndProject
```

The second reference appears in the Global section, where you need to define the build configurations:

```
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|x64 = Debug|x64
        Release|x64 = Release|x64
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {A1EEBF59-8295-4354-927F-CE696137BF5C}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64
        {A1EEBF59-8295-4354-927F-CE696137BF5C}.Debug|x64.Build.0 = Debug|x64
        {A1EEBF59-8295-4354-927F-CE696137BF5C}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|x64
        {A1EEBF59-8295-4354-927F-CE696137BF5C}.Release|x64.Build.0 = Release|x64
```

As the OP mentioned, he manually deleted the first reference to the project but forgot about the second one. The easiest way to find the second reference is by searching the `.sln` file by project ID or by identifying the ID that no longer exists if the first reference has already been deleted.

Usually, I use Notepad++ because it has a highlight option.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

After revisiting solution file I found out that duplicates were in fact in the other section of the file

```
{F853C9A7-7E99-48A2-AB4F-0D48E150853B}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
{F853C9A7-7E99-48A2-AB4F-0D48E150853B}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
{F853C9A7-7E99-48A2-AB4F-0D48E150853B}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
{F853C9A7-7E99-48A2-AB4F-0D48E150853B}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
```

Somewhere there was a duplicate of this 4 lines
Deleted them and everything works now